# How do I convert a page of HTML to a page on my Rails site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, html-parsing

I added an upload form so people can upload HTML files to my site. How do I parse a file of HTML to create a page of content on the site? Currently, I just need to get the title and body of a file, so I thought a full-blown parser like Nokogiri would be overkill.

```
#this takes in a <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile>
def import(file)
  #code to get title and body?
end
```

Comment: A parser like Nokogiri may still be best. Parsing HTML isn't joyful, especially if it's invalidly nested in any way.

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways to do this..

You can open and read the file from your controller assuming you saved it to an object somewhere.

```
@content = File.read(@your_saved_object.attachment.file_name)
```

And then in your view ( in Haml ) :

```
#content-container= @content
```